# Flutter Bloc : No ancestor could be found starting from the context?

Tags: flutter

I'm new to Flutter, and also new to Bloc use.

I have an error when compiling the code:

```
    The following assertion was thrown building Login(dirty, state: _LoginFormState#44e7f):
         BlocProvider.of() called with a context that does not contain a Bloc of type BtnBloc.
         No ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to
         BlocProvider.of<BtnBloc>().
       This can happen if the context you use comes from a widget above the BlocProvider.
         This can also happen if you used BlocProviderTree and didn't explicity provide 
         the BlocProvider types: BlocProvider(bloc: BtnBloc()) instead of BlocProvider<BtnBloc>(bloc:
         BtnBloc()).
         The context used was: Login(dirty, state: _LoginFormState#44e7f)
```

I've tried to change some stuff in my bloc class, but nothing does about it.

Here is my blog class :

```
class BtnBloc extends Bloc<BtnEvent, BtnState> {
  @override
  BtnState get initialState => BtnState.initial();

  @override
  Stream<BtnState> mapEventToState(
      BtnState currentState, BtnEvent event) async* {
    if (event is IdleEvent) {
      yield currentState..state = 1;
    } else if (event is LoadingEvent) {
      yield currentState..state = 1;
    } else if (event is RevealEvent) {
      yield currentState..state = 2;
    }
  }
}
```

And here is my build method :

```
final _btnBloc = new BtnBloc();

  _LoginFormState(
      {Key key,
      this.primaryColor,
      this.backgroundColor,
      this.backgroundImage,
      this.logo});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider(
        bloc: _btnBloc,
        child: BlocBuilder<BtnEvent, BtnState>(
            bloc: BlocProvider.of<BtnBloc>(context),
            builder: (context, BtnState state) {
return myWidget();
```

Please help me :'(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line below is your problem. The error is exactly what the message says.

```
...
child: BlocBuilder<BtnEvent, BtnState>(
     bloc: BlocProvider.of<BtnBloc>(context), <------- Problem line
     builder: (context, BtnState state) {
...
```

The context you're using there does not have a BlocBuilder attached to it so nothing is passing the BloC down from the top to your LoginState. You can either

1. Use your existing bloc (_btnBloc) and pass it in (**recommended**)
2. Wrap the widget putting the LoginState on screen with a BlocProvider so that you have access to it in the widget state.

If this is your first view then use 1.

Change

```
 bloc: BlocProvider.of<BtnBloc>(context), <------- Problem line
```

To

```
bloc: _btnBloc
```

Comment: @VincentGuillois Happy to have helped.

Answer (score 9):

After the while of time facing this problem, I hope [this article](https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-context-and-of-method-110409311517) will help you to understand more about `context`.
The general solution is the same as the @Filled Stacks's answer. It means that you have to [pass the bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) when navigating into a new page, so the `BlocProvider` can find which type of Bloc you will be received.

I recommend initing the main function for the overall application which will init your screens and context through the screens.
For eg:

- Init and passing Bloc:

```dart
class ListTodoPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocProvider<TodoBloc>(
        create: (context) => TodoBloc(TodoDao())..add(QueryTodoEvent()),
        child: ListTodoPageful());
  }
}

class ListTodoPageful extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return ListTodoState();
  }
}

class ListTodoState extends State<ListTodoPageful> {
  TodoBloc _todoBloc;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _todoBloc = BlocProvider.of<TodoBloc>(
        context);
   //...
   floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
              context,
              CupertinoPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => BlocProvider.value(
                      value: _todoBloc, child: CreateTaskPage())));
        }
  //...
}
```

- Receive Bloc:

```dart
class _CreatePageState extends State<CreateTaskPage> {
  TodoBloc _todoBloc;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _todoBloc = BlocProvider.of<TodoBloc>(context);
}
```

Refer to my sample application here: https://github.com/huynguyennovem/flutter_todo