# Flutter BlocProvider: No ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed?

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

according to the flutter_bloc documentation it is sufficient to wrap a widget with Bloc Provider in order to use the Bloc instance from the widget. However, I am getting this error:

No ancestor could be found starting from the context that was passed to BlocProvider.of().

My code is very simple, structured in the following way:

login_screen.dart

```
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  
  final TextEditingController _usernameController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwortController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return BlocProvider(
      create: (context) => AuthenticationBloc(),
      child: Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
            title: Text(widget.title),
          ),
          body: Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [

                //Username
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _usernameController,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Email",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder()
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
    
                //Passwort:
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: _passwortController,
                    obscureText: true,
                    decoration: const InputDecoration(
                      labelText: "Password",
                      border: OutlineInputBorder()
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
    
                //Login button
                ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    minimumSize: const Size(200, 50)
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {

                    BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context).add(
                      LoginEvent(_usernameController.text, _passwortController.text)
                    );
    
                  }, 
                  child: const Text('Log in')
                ),
                const SizedBox(height: 20,),
                //Register button
                ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                    minimumSize: const Size(200, 50)
                  ),
                  onPressed: () async {
    
                  },
                  child: const Text('Register')
                ),
              ],
            ),)
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

main.dart

```
void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  await service_registration.init();

  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const LoginPage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}
```

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Your problem same like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55334005/9597017). Maybe it can give you a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to rename "context" in create parameter to something else?

from:

```
create: (context) => AuthenticationBloc()
```

to

```
create: (context2) => AuthenticationBloc()
```

Sometimes happens to get the wrong context and, obviously, there will be no Bloc there.

But I highly recommend you to provide blocs right before MaterialApp, on MyApp class. Just like below:

```
  class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => AuthenticationBloc(),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => MySecondBloc(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
           colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
           useMaterial3: true,
        ),
      home: const LoginPage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

By doing this, you can access your bloc anywhere your application. Just be aware to not fetch a big amount of data right on blocstart

Answer (score 0):

[BlocProvider.of() Fails to Find Bloc](https://bloclibrary.dev/#/faqs?id=blocproviderof-fails-to-find-bloc)

The problem is that BlocProvider.of() is using the context that was provided for BlocProvider.

```
 BlocProvider.of<AuthenticationBloc>(context).add(LoginEvent(_usernameController.text, _passwortController.text));
```

There are many ways to solve this issue; you just need to ensure that blocProvider.of() uses the child BuildContext. For example, you can wrap your Scaffold with BlocBuilder(), BlocConsumer(), or Builder().